# What are the implications of Lean not having the type `Set`?

Tags: type-theory, proof-assistants, coq

In [Coq](https://coq.inria.fr/) we have an impredicative base type, called `Prop`, and a predicative base type, called `Set`, both of type `Type 0`.

On the other hand, in [Lean](https://leanprover.github.io/) we only have an impredicative base type. We do not have an equivalent to `Set`. Instead we use directly `Type 0`(a synonym of `Sort 1`).

What are the implications of this design decision?

Comment: I think [this](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/a/21878/28789) almost answers it. Would you agree?

Comment: @chi Nice reference, but, in my limited understanding, I do not think this answers the question. I understand what is the purpose of `Prop`. The real question is what power adds to the system the introduction of `Set` (as in Coq) while using `Type 0` directly (as in Lean) is sufficient. Maybe it has some relation with Coq having cumulative universes while Lean having not.

Comment: I would agree. I think the main reason of having Prop is just predicativity. What other reasons do you think there might be?

Comment: @xuq01 Both of you are right, but this question is not about `Prop` but about the presence/absence of `Set`. What are the advantages of having it (Coq) when you can live without it (Lean)? It increases the complexity of the system (this is a big thing for a theorem prover) so there must be a reason.

Comment: The linked answer still answers it. `Set` is predicative, so it has large elimination; `Prop` is impredicative, so it does not have large elimination.

Comment: @xuq01 So this means that `Type 0` doesn't have large elimination?

Comment: @user3368561 IIRC, I think it doesn't have impredicativity.

Answer (score 2):

In Coq `Set` behaves basically like the smallest possible `Type`. Unlike Coq however, Lean lets you select the "level" of the type manually, such as `Type 9` (or `Sort 10`), something which is not allowed in Coq - meaning that you do not need `Set` in Lean, you can just use `Type 0` (or just `Type`, or `Sort 1`) instead as it is basically the same thing.
I should also note that in Lean `Prop` is the same as `Sort 0` (or `Sort`) (which does not have large elimination) and `Type n` (for `n : nat`) is the same as `Sort (n + 1)` (which has large elimination).

TL;DR: `Type` (with no "arguments") is the `Set` of Lean

Comment: But in Coq `Prop` and `Set` are of the same type while in Lean they are not; in Lean one of them is in fact an element of the other. Does this have any significance to the logic theory behind?

Comment: @user3368561 As far as I know the only significance is that only Prop can be impredicative in Lean while in Coq both Prop and Set can be impredicative (as long as you stay in the bounds of intuitionistic type theory) - as only the lowest member(s) of the hierarchy can be impredicative if you do not want paradoxes.